# ABAP Debugger Enlarge function scope line - SAP GUI 7.60 patch 2

Tags: user-interface, debugging, abap

Scope does not show enough information regarding cursor position in code.
How can I enlarge scope line in ABAP Debugger on the standard tab?

[image: Scope is too short]

Comment: thanks everyone for suggestions, removing and clean installation of SAP GUI 7.50 solved the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing and clean installation of SAP GUI 7.50 solved the problem.

Backup connections before removing:
https://answers.sap.com/questions/409243/saving-connections-list-in-sap-logon.html

Answer (score 1):

Probably a bug in your SAP GUI version. You should install the latest version.

See in SAP GUI 7.50 how the elements look better; the "scope" is left-aligned and has the biggest width possible, and all other information are right-aligned and their size is minimal:

[image: Backend ABAP debugger]

Answer (score 0):

I suppose this is resolution-dependent. On my 1920x1280 it goes fine out-of-the-box.

Did you try to drag the splitter between the editor and variable tab?

[image]

Usually it helps

[image]